# Script to extract source domains from a DNS Zone file is not skipping lines with leading whitespace

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking to sanitize our DNS Zone file in order to extract source domains containing only `CNAME` and `A` records and eliminate all the comments, `TXT`, `MX`, and `SRV` records. Most importantly, I would like to automate this process.

I've managed to create a RegEx that can be used to perform a Find and Replace in Sublime Text and takes a few iterations to achieve the required outcome.

Let's take the following sample DNS Zone file as an example:

```
$ORIGIN example.com.
@                      3600 SOA   ns1.p30.dynect.net. (
                              zone-admin.dyndns.com.     ; address of responsible party
                              2016072701                 ; serial number
                      86400 IN  NS  ns1.p30.dynect.net.
                       3600 IN  MX  10 mail.example.com.
                         60 IN  A   204.13.248.106
abc                        TXT      "v=spf1 includespf.dynect.net ~all"
mail                        IN  A        204.13.248.106
vpn                         IN  TXT    v=spf1 includespf.dynect.net ~all"
vpn2                      IN  MX     v=spf1 includespf.dynect.net ~all"
webapp                      IN  A        216.146.46.10
#webapp1                  IN  A       216.146.46.10
xyz                         IN  CNAME     example.com.
webapp                      IN  SRV     216.146.46.11
;webapp2                  IN    A         216.146.46.11
```

Step 1

Use this for "Find"

```
(^;.*)|(^#.*)|(^\$.*)|(^@.*)|(.*IN\h+MX.*)|(.*IN\h+TXT.*)|(.*IN\h+SRV.*)|(.*IN\h+NS.*)|(.*\h+TXT.*)|(\h.+)|(^[\n\r\h]+)
```

and replace with nothing.

This will clean the Zone file and display only the source domains that point to `CNAME` and `A` records.

Step 2

Use the following for "Find"

```
(.+$)
```

and replace it with

```
\1.example.com
```

The result is a list of source domains appended with the origin domain:

```
mail.example.com
webapp.example.com
xyz.example.com
```

I'm now attempting to write a Python script that does the above for a given Zone file and outputs it to a `.txt` file.

[Wiktor Stribiżew](//stackoverflow.com/u/3832970), a RegEx & Python god here at Stack Overflow, helped me write the following:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'^(?:\s+|[;#$@].*)|.*IN\s+(?:MX|TXT|SRV|NS).*|.*\s+TXT.*|\s.+')
with open('1.txt', 'r',encoding='UTF8') as dns:
    with open('2.txt', 'w',encoding='UTF8') as output:
        for line in dns:
            if line.strip():
                line = regex.sub('', line.strip())
                if line:
                    output.write("{}.example.com\n".format(line))
```

Unfortunately, the output for the script is this:

```
zone-admin.dyndns.com..example.com
2016072701.example.com
60.example.com
mail.example.com
webapp.example.com
xyz.example.com
```

The script is not omitting lines that begin with a white space. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have two errors, each of which will lead to the incorrect use of lines beginning with white-space.

The first error is in the statement

```
line = regex.sub('', line.strip())
```

which strips any leading white-space *before* passing the line to the`sub()` method. Thus the regex never sees any lines beginning with white-space.

To fix this, the `strip()` method needs to be called *after* the `sub()` method has been called:

```
line = regex.sub('', line).strip()
```

Note that the whole reason for the `strip()` is so that trailing newline characters are removed, setting `line` to an empty string for lines that are to be ignored. A simple test can be used to check for this, since empty strings are falsy.

As an alternative, this call could be omitted and instead the regex could be modified to remove the newlines. (This would be done by replacing all the "trailing" `.*`'s with `[\s\S]*`'s.)

The second error is in your regular expression, which just matches the leading white-space part of the line instead of the line in its entirety. This causes the `sub()` method to essentially strip leading white-space!
[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/7FRFRf/1)  <sup>1</sup>

```
regex = re.compile(r'^(?:\s+|[;#$@].*)|.*IN\s+(?:MX|TXT|SRV|NS).*|.*\s+TXT.*|\s.+')
                         ↑_↑
                          |
  only matches the leading white-space part, not the whole line
```

The quick fix is to move forward the non-capturing group's closing bracket:
[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/7FRFRf/2)  <sup>1</sup>

```
regex = re.compile(r'^(?:\s+|[;#$@]).*|.*IN\s+(?:MX|TXT|SRV|NS).*|.*\s+TXT.*|\s.+')
                                   ↑ ↓
                                    ←
```

Note that a simpler regex can be created by realising that the white-space meta-character `\s` can be moved inside the character class, and that we only need to check the first character of the line:
[Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/7FRFRf/3)  <sup>1</sup>

```
regex = re.compile(r'^[\s;#$@].*|.*IN\s+(?:MX|TXT|SRV|NS).*|.*\s+TXT.*|\s.+')
```

Finally, a further simplification can be achieved by matching every non-comment, non-leading white-space line that does *not* point to a CNAME or A record, using a negative lookahead, rather than explicitly and exhaustively matching lines that point to non-CNAME/non-A records:
[Demo 4](https://regex101.com/r/7FRFRf/4)  <sup>1</sup>

```
regex = re.compile(r'^(?:[\s;#$@]|(?!.*IN\s+[AC])).*|\s.+')
```

Or if you prefer less nesting (plus it's one character shorter ;-) ):
[Demo 5](https://regex101.com/r/7FRFRf/5)  <sup>1</sup>

```
regex = re.compile(r'^[\s;#$@].*|^(?!.*IN\s+[AC]).*|\s.+')
```

This is the full working version of your code using the last regex above:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'^[\s;#$@].*|^(?!.*IN\s+[AC]).*|\s.+')
with open('1.txt', 'r',encoding='UTF8') as dns:
    with open('2.txt', 'w',encoding='UTF8') as output:
        for line in dns:
            if line.strip():
                line = regex.sub('', line).strip()
                if line:
                    output.write("{}.example.com\n".format(line))
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> All the demo regexes have been tweaked (the last white-space meta-character `\s` has been replaced with a space) to allow the multi line flag to be used to show all the resulting lines with the substitutions done (in the "SUBSTITUTION" box). This doesn't affect the functionality of the regexes since the test string only contains spaces and newlines and no other white-space.</sub>

Comment: thank you very much. Unfortunately, the output isn't as expected. I believe the code is replacing every line that doesn't match with CNAME or A record by appending .example.com
Please use the above DNS file content as input file and try to run your code. You'll know what I'm talking about.

Comment: @DataShark Ah, yes  Should have actually *run* the code  I forgot that you actually *do* need to use `strip()` to remove the newline character(s) at the end of each line so that the check to see if `line` is falsy (empty) and needs to be ignored works. You just need to do it *after* calling `sub()`. I've  edited my answer to fix this.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks again. Also, I've appended the following code ```uniqlines = set(open('2.txt').readlines())
bar = open('2.txt', 'w').writelines(sorted(set(uniqlines)))``` that will remove duplicates and sort the unique lines.